# How to perform logical inclusive OR operation on hexadecimal numbers?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

In logic there is so called OR operation that is quite clear to me as long as it is in the binary system. For example, if I want to OR such binary values as "101" (which corresponds to decimal "5") and "110" (which corresponds to decimal "6"), you would do it this way:

101

+

110

=

111

The logic here is quite clear: if there is at least one "1", then the result must also be "1".

However, I have no idea how this operation can be performed on hexadecimal numbers.
For example, if I needed to OR such hexadecimal values as "1A" (which corresponds to decimal "26") and "1F" (which corresponds to decimal "31"), how would i do that than?

1A

+

1F

=

??

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To expand on copper.hat’s answer just a little, observe that every hexadecimal digit corresponds to a string of four bits:

$$\begin{array}{c|c}
\text{Hex}&\text{Bin}\\ \hline
0&0000\\
1&0001\\
2&0010\\
3&0011\\
4&0100\\
5&0101\\
6&0110\\
7&0111\\
8&1000\\
9&1001\\
A&1010\\
B&1011\\
C&1100\\
D&1101\\
E&1110\\
F&1111
\end{array}$$

Thus, any hexadecimal number converts very easily to binary: just convert the individual digits. Hex $B94A$, for instance converts to $1011\;1001\;0100\; 1010$. (That conversion is practically hard-wired, since I earned my spending money in college writing IBM 360 assembler language programs!)

Comment: Engineers used to (and still do) use some particular bit patterns because they are easily recognizable in hex. For example, AAAA, 5555, DEADBEEF,...

Comment: For quick reference, you can even make a 16-by-16 table of the results, all in hexadecimals. Well, maybe that's not quicker :P BTW, I like copper.hat's DEADBEEF!

Answer (score 4):

Treat the hex number as binary. $\text{1A}_{16} = 11010_2$, $\text{1F}_{16} = 11111_2$, so the 'or' is clearly $\text{1F}_{16}$.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers here are based on converting from hexadecimal to binary, then computing a bitwise OR. I would like to propose a different method without converting to a different base.

Where my idea comes from: (not-tested)
A standard diode in electronics only allows electricity to go one way. A simple OR gate in electronics  is two diodes pointing into each other. If you were to put a high voltage through one side (F) the output would be that same voltage (F). Even if you added a lower voltage (A) to the other input, the output would remain the same as the output is already at a higher voltage.

So, our current OR gates really end up being "Which Ever Is Greater" gates. That would mean your example of 1A+1F = 1F. Also, 5B+A0=AB. This is very different than a binary bitwise OR, but that is because it is a "true" hexadecimal bitwise OR.

Comment: Also, NOT can be though of (100% - value%). When dealing with only 1s and 0s (100%s and 0%s) this is pretty simple: not(1)=1-1=0, not(0)=1-0=1, but we can follow the same rules for hexadecimal. not(5)=F-5=A, not(A)=F-A=5. (This is similar in concept to the not used on subsets of sets as well)

Comment: Using Not and Or, and DeMorgan's Law, we can create an And gate too! XY=(X'+Y')' so in hexadecimal: XY=(F-((F-X)+(F-Y))) which ends up being a "Which Ever Is Least" gate. This (and the other two) makes sense with any Natural Number based number systems.

Comment: This doesn't work if both of the numbers are powers of 2. For example: 0x4 && 0x2 != 0x4, 0x2 || 0x2 != 0x4